# Generate camunda Report By Process not by test case

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, camunda

I have create a project with camunda coverage for spring that generate reports html to see the coverage of your unit test method.

what i want is to generate a report by process not method, for example if i have three method of unit test that test the same process(A) but for differente branches the generated report will contain the sum of all this methods in one HTML report file.

Thanks.